# C# : Calling a Method out of console application

Tags: c#, console

I have a console app, that is used for importing stuff from a WS.

I'm really new to Console Apps so I have a question.

The Project contains a class called Importer.cs. This class has a Method called Initialize():

```
class Importer
{
    static void  Initialize()
    {
        //here i connect to the server etc.
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to call my APP like:

```
Importer.exe Initialize
```

So it should call the Initialize method, and then I would like to be able to go on with for example:

```
Importer.exe StartImport
```

I already work with the args[] parameter, but i'm quite stuck now.

Comment: you can't do that but try to use class library project and add its output `dll` to references

Comment: You'll have to learn how to use Reflection so you can translate a string like "Initialize" to a MethodInfo object.  It is very unlikely to be a useful exercise, other than knowing how to use Reflection after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like CommandLineParser and then use Reflection to call these method as MethodInfo objects.

Comment: I will try this. looks interesting

Answer (score 0):

In your console application, look in your solution explorer (in the right window of VS where all your files are shown). Find the one called PROGRAM.CS. Open it and look for this:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
```

Inside that, put this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //This starts a new instance of the Importer Class
       Importer myImporter = new Importer();
       //This calls the Initialize Method within Importer
       Importer.Initialize();
       //This calls the StartInput() Method within Importer
       Importer.StartInput();    
       //Use Console.ReadLine() as the last line in this method to keep your screen open after program execution ends.
       Console.ReadLine();       
    }
```

The first thing your console app runs ins Main() in console app.

Then, you simply test the project using F5. After testing, build the project and run by double-clicking the EXE file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're exactly doing, this might not even work. I imagine a situation, where you `Initialize()` and afterwards `StartImport()`, but in between these 2 calls the program has been finished and the initialized state is gone. If you do not have methods like `Initialize()`, but rather atomic subcommands, your approach is possible in principle.

But there arises one question: Is this going to be generic? I mean: Say, you add another method. Do you then want to have the access to the method by a subcommand automatically established or wouldn't you mind adding another subcommand case? The first option would mean, you need to get comfortable with Reflection.

Now, say, you add methods, which you cannot declare private due to whatever reason, but you don't want them to be exposed as a subcommand. So you would need to keep track of the visibility. Sure, this would mean poor design, but if you're stuck with legacy components, this might just happen.

Now, let's say you need the `Initialize()` (or similar) command(s). They take care of a connection state or whatever and the program needs to still run, when the next subcommand is invoked, so it can use the initialized information, handles, etc.. Wouldn't it then make more sense to design your console application like a shell? So you would start with `Importer.exe` and get asked for subcommands.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guy just wants to know how to run his class methods in a console app environment. He's thinking he needs to pass them as command line args

Comment: Sure, but I think he got that point, that this isn't trivial and the actual point of my answer is, that such a command after command design might not work for what he is trying to do.

Comment: Amen to that! Cheers!